# In memory OLTP RAM requirement

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-database, oltp, sql-server-2016

I'm considering **moving** at least parts of a business application **to memory optimized tables with SQL 2016**. I'd also convert the current stored procedures into natively compiled procedures.

I've read articles about in memory OLTP, but I have not found extensive info on **increased RAM need** for such a DB. My assumption is that we'll need to upgrade from wherever we are right now to more.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I would suggest starting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282389.aspx

Comment: Rough estimate is probably 2x your size of data for more RAM. Brent Ozar has some points: http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/hekaton-memory-oltp-tables-use/

Comment: great comments, many thanks both of you. I'll be reviewing these materials. If eventually we go for partial transformation to memory based tables, I'll post the results.

Comment: This isn't a question for StackOverflow - it's a resource provisioning question. Not a programming question.